# VMWare ESX 4.1 Deploy Linux from template and DO NOT customise

Tags: linux, vmware-esx

Having spent some time on a nice prebaked linux template, I'm somewhat disappointed to discover that when I clone this template and clearly choose to NOT customise, it gets customised.

Specifically, an interface configuration changes from 
`ONBOOT="no"` to `ONBOOT="yes"`, which means someone needs to log in and changing it.

All the virtual machines should be the same, only the the first interface needs to be configured and that will come from dhcp servers, and I would really like eth1 to remain down initially.

Would anyone know what is running against the template and changing /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth* ?

Comment: could you please comment on what distribution are you using?

Comment: @Sergei RHEL 5.8

Comment: I think the best-practice these days is to redeploy versus clone (for Linux). With kickstart, post-install and configuration management, it's almost faster to do so. There *should* be a way to do what you're asking, though. I just think that the customization/cloning options for Linux on VMWare are limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought that the MAC address of the virtual nic changes when you clone and hence it is more likely that it is the linux startup scripts that change the configuration instead of something from VMware?

Comment: No, I hadnt considered that, and you might have hit the nail on the head. So, in 3 weeks when I return to work, I'll investigate.